# Query Cancelled Error when trying to use photo from camera roll in app in IOS 11 / Swift 4.0 -

Tags: ios, swift, image, ios11, photolibrary

I have used a variety of solutions offered in other posts including permission settings in infoplist. I'd love any advice anyone could lend.

Additionally, I've tried a variety of photo picker functions and have coded a variety of functions that try to establish permission programmatically but continue to get the "query cancelled" error. I'm fairly certain this is some sort of permission problem, but at this point I don't have much of an idea of where to direct my changes/ modifications.

In general, what I'm attempting to do is click the open photo library button, select a photo, and display it in the app. Right now, I have the methods for opening the photo library and selecting a photo working. In this latter step, the use photo button returns me back to the main subview of my app or returns the query error.

```
import UIKit
import MathSwift
import MobileCoreServices
import QuartzCore
import Photos


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


var cameraButtonView = UIButton()
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var imageTaken = UIImage()
var imagePicked = UIImageView()

var doMath = Math()
//@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var cameraButtonView = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 467, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100.0))
    cameraButtonView.setTitle("Open Camera", for: .normal)
    cameraButtonView.backgroundColor = .green
    cameraButtonView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openCameraButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(cameraButtonView)

    var libButtonView = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 567, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100.0))
    libButtonView.setTitle("Open Photo Library", for: .normal)
    libButtonView.backgroundColor = .red
    libButtonView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openPhotoLibraryButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(libButtonView)

     imagePicked = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    view.addSubview(imagePicked)


    checkPermission()
}

func checkPermission() {
    let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        print("Access is granted by user")
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
            (newStatus) in
            print("status is \(newStatus)")
            if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                /* do stuff here */
                print("success")
            }
        })
        print("It is not determined until now")
    case .restricted:
        // same same
        print("User do not have access to photo album.")
    case .denied:
        // same same
        print("User has denied the permission.")
    }
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    checkPermission()
    //imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
    //imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

var newMedia: Bool?
@IBAction func captureImageButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //let imageName : String = "dolphin"
    //randomImageView.image = UIImage.init(named:imageName)

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true,
                     completion: nil)
        newMedia = true
    }
}


@IBAction func openCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {
     print("button tapped")
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

@IBAction func openPhotoLibraryButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

 internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

//        let theInfo : NSDictionary = info as NSDictionary
//        let image = theInfo.object(forKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    print("image")
    imagePicked.image = image
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func saveButt(sender: AnyObject) {
    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagePicked.image!, 0.6)
    var compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPGImage!, nil, nil, nil)

    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Wow",
                            message: "Your image has been saved to Photo Library!",
                            delegate: nil,
                            cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
    alert.show()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 }
```

}

Comment: Do you have the info.plist entry for "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" setup?